# Magento URl error with PHP

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, mage

I installed fresh magento 1.9.2.2. While installing and after it instaled, whenever i try my domain url the same error have been coming like shown below.
    Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 50

```
Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/website/php') in /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/website/php') in /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/website/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 54
```

So I used

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx *[my ip address]*/~website/

then in installtion I changed my path to my domain name. Its not working.

Anyone know any solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem caused by the .htaccess file. Try to rename it to test this idea or check rewrite/redirect rules.